# Return multiple rows for cells containing lists

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have something like this in a postgres db:

```
| foo | 1,2 | a,b |
```

And I want to expand it to:

```
| foo | 1 | a |
| foo | 2 | b |
```

I know I can do this with plpgsql but wondering whether there was a way to it with sql.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this demo:

```
SELECT name
      ,unnest(a)
      ,unnest(b)
FROM  (VALUES ('foo', '{1,2}'::int[], '{a,b}'::text[])) t(name, a, b)
```

Result:

```
 name | unnest | unnest
------+--------+--------
 foo  |      1 | a
 foo  |      2 | b
(2 rows)
```

Or, if you have comma-separated strings and not ARRAYs:

```
SELECT name
      ,regexp_split_to_table(a, ',')
      ,regexp_split_to_table(b, ',')
FROM  (VALUES ('foo', '1,2'::text, 'a,b'::text)) t(name, a, b)
```

Same Result.
More about [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) and [`regexp_split_to_table()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting a one to one relationship between the list items, assuming there are multiple lists in each row, or is there some relationship between the items so you always want A tied to 1 and b tied to 2?

From a single straight sql statement, not really.  I think you would have to use a stored procedure and loop through the table.  If it is feeding in to an application, you can grab everything in one sql statement then use your code to loop through it and break out the lists from each row.